# Collection+JSON with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, collections

I'm working on a project where various tables of data will be displayed with AngularJS. The data will be in the Collection+JSON format, as shown below. I found this library https://github.com/Medycation/angular-collection-json, I'm not sure how to make it work. Below is an example of the data.

```
angular.module('app', ['cj']);

var $injector = angular.injector();
var cj = $injector.get('cj');

cj("cjapi1.php").then(function(cjProvider){
     console.log(collection.items());
});
```

I tried the above. In the console it says I need to register cjProvider as a provider. Any help with how to set this up properly would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
  “collection”: 
  {
    “version”:  “0.1”,
    “href” :  “https://example.com/companies”
    “items” : [
         {
“href” : “https://example.com/companies/123”,
“data” : [
  {
    “orgInfo”: {
           {“name”: “companyName”,  “value”: “Example Company 1”}
                 }
         },
         {
“href” : “https://example.com/companies/1234”,
“data” : [
  {
    “orgInfo”: {
           {“name”: “companyName”,  “value”: “Example Company 2”}
                 }
         },
     ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please configure your cjProvider while configuring your module. Check the below code template for the reference to configure cjProvider.

```
angular.module('app', ['cj']).configure(function(cjProvider){

  // Alter urls before they get requested
  // cj('http://example.com/foo') requests http://example.com/foo/improved
  cjProvider.setUrlTransform(function(original){
    return original + '/improved';
  });

  // Disable strict version checking (collections without version "1.0")
  cjProvider.setStrictVersion(false);

});
```

Please make sure that you have configured your transformUrl just shown above.

Your base url must be configured in cjProvider and while hitting any url ang getting data you should transform your request like here you are requesting `cjapi1.php`. so your baseurl must be append before that like `your_base_url + 'cjapi1.php'` this will be done for all requesting api. So cjProvider will take care that and will return api path and in `.then(responce)` you will get your responce which is collection.

```
cj("cjapi1.php").then(function(collection){
     console.log(collection.items());
});
```

Comment: tried this. I'm getting TypeError: angular.module(...).configure is not a function. I exluded the set urlTransform since I'm not changing the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to configure or get the contents of the collection from php call?

Looks like a typo to me but try this to get collection:

```
cj("cjapi1.php").then(function(collection){
     console.log(collection.items());
});
```

...and this for configuration of your provider:

```
    angular.module('agile', ['cj']).configure(function(cjProvider){

  // Alter urls before they get requested
  // cj('http://example.com/foo') requests http://example.com/foo/improved
  cjProvider.setUrlTransform(function(original){
    return original + '/improved';
  });

  // Disable strict version checking (collections without version "1.0")
  cjProvider.setStrictVersion(false);

});
```

Comment: the php file echos the Collection+JSON. I tried the above and get TypeError: angular.module(...).configure is not a function

Comment: ok, try this: var app = angular.module("agile", ['cj']); app.config(function(cjProvider){ ... })

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cjProvider <- cj
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=cjProvider%20%3C-%20cj